# Touch input to pan through video using VR SDK?

Tags: google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Iam developing an application to Play 360 videos, everything is working fine but i want to include touch input to pan through the video along with gyro input. Is there any way to include it? Does VR SDK supports this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's build in the sdk but there is this:
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html